# WSO2 IS - Oauth SP + UserStore restriction

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an OAuth2 service provider with password credentials in WSO2 IS and I need that just users from a userStore can get a token. I have tried using XACML policies with now success.

Is it possible to deny the OAuth token request per userStore?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support userstore preference during the authentication flow, you can use application-authentication extension explained here https://medium.com/@anuradha.15/how-to-configure-your-preferred-user-stores-to-authenticate-users-for-a-service-provider-in-wso2-cdadf43f9366. However, this feature is supported WSO2-IS 5.9.0 onwards. Hope this will satisfy your requirement.